# Как сделать страницу стартовой?

Tags: html, javascript

```
<a href="#" onClick="this.style.behavior="url(#default#homepage)"; this.setHomePage("http://gazetam.net/"); return false;"> Сделать страницу стартовой</a>
```

Что-то этот код не сильно и работает.

Answer (score 4):

[How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Может код не работает, потому что в onclick="" Вы используете несколько пар одинаковых кавычек? Это ведь запрещено, попробуйте вот так:

```
<a href="#" onсlick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; this.setHomePage('http://gazetam.net/'); return false;"> Сделать страницу стартовой</a>
```

Comment: Почему же тогда везде указан "мой" метод? дезинформация?

Comment: Вполне может быть)

Answer (score -2):

Вот тут лучшее описание как сделать стартовую страницу в популярных браузерах https://ifish2.ru/sdelat-stranitsu-startovoj/ теперь и вы легко можете это сделать)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]